# Java Method not Implementing

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I created a small Java program that basically draws a keyboard controllable circle and some "walls" in a JFrame. Here's what it looks like when executed;

[image: http://prntscr.com/3lvy7w]

The program has 3 classes:

1. **main.java**  (the main method class)
2. **Infout.java** (circle + walls constructor class)
3. **world.java**  (the class that draws the JFrame)

Here is the code:

**main.java**

```
 public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    world w = new world();
    Infout o = new Infout();

    w.frame();

}

   }
```

**world.java**

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;


  public class world {

JFrame f = new JFrame();
Infout o = new Infout();

public void frame(){
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    f.setSize(300, 400);
    f.setTitle("Circle");
    f.add(o);

}
   }
```

**Infout.java**

```
 import javax.swing.*;

 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Infout extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    double x = 0, y = 0, velx = 0, vely = 0;

    public Infout(){

        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40));
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 270, 300, 5));
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(140, 270, 5, 300));
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(140, 60, 70, 5));
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(50, 140, 5, 70));
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(150, 130, 5, 40));
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(190, 210, 40, 5));
        if (x >= 120 && y >= 270) {
            g.drawString("You win!",115,35);
        }
        if (x <= 120 && y >= 270) {
            g.drawString("You lose!",115,35);
        }
        if (x == 120 && y >= 270){
            velx = 0;
            vely = 0;
        }
        if (x == 31.5 && y <= 200 && y >= 100){
            velx = 0;
        }
        if (x == 132 && y <= 170 && y >= 100){
            velx = 0;
        }
        if (x <= 190 && x >= 120 && y == 42){
            velx = 0;
        }
        if (x <= 210 && x >= 171 && y == 192){
            velx = 0;
        }

    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        System.out.println("x "+x+"y "+y);

        repaint();
        x += velx;
        y += vely;

        if (x < 0 || x > 260)
        {
            velx = 0;
            vely = 0;
        }
        if (y < 0 || y > 340)
        {
            velx = 0;
            vely = 0;
        }
    }

    public void up() {
        vely = -1.5;
        velx = 0;
    }

    public void down() {
        vely = 1.5;
        velx = 0;
    }

    public void left() {
        velx = -1.5;
        vely = 0;
    }

    public void right() {
        velx = 1.5;
        vely = 0;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            down();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left();
        }

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
     }
```

The problem is the circle is not moving when I try to move it with the keyboard keys! :(. All the code in **Infout.java** is correct because I used this same class is another program and I was able to move the circle around :/

Thanks!

Ab

Comment: first of all debug you code and make sure that the key listeners are being invoked... try to understand your code

Comment: What happens when you add `repaint()` after all of your `if` statements in your `keyPressed` method?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that class. I think it has something to do with the main method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the `actionPerformed` method?

If not, then the panel is probably not repainting itself

Comment: Where should I call the actionPerformed method?

Comment: Well, you should register it to a Component. Anyways I would not put the repaint logic in an actionPerformed event in an application like yours, you should probably have an infinite loop that repaints the panel every now and then. The screen will probably flicker, but that's another problem for another topic